# Modify bashrc & .profile from safe mode

Tags: 12.04, recovery-mode

I have messed up `.bashrc` & `.profile` in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Can I change it back to previous version from safe mode  as I am not able to login to my system and I think this might be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that through safe mode, just need to mount the partition in read-write mode with this command : `mount -o remount,rw /`. This command is necessary  because in recovery mode the Ubuntu portion of hard drive is mounted in read-only mode and you cannot make changes to files.  `rw` option tells ubuntu to allow read-write access to Ubuntu part of the disk. And yes, it is needed before running `vim /home/yourusername/.bashrc`.

You can get to safe mode aka recovery mode, by selecting "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in the boot menu, then recovery mode (if you have multiple ones there, don't freak out - any of them is OK). Then access the root shell, and run the command I mentioned above. After that you can proceed with editing `.bashrc` or `.profile` with a text editor such as `nano` or `vi`

Notice also, that in recovery mode, you don't need `sudo` as in recovery mode you automatically logged in as root. You will also need to navigate to your nome directory to edit `.bashrc` or `.profile` by running `cd /home/yourusername` Notice that if you are logged in as root `sudo ~/.bashrc` is for root's .bashrc. Tilde expands to current users' home directory, and if you are logged in as root, it will expand to root's home directory. This is why you need to run `vi /home/yourusername/.bashrc`

Comment: is `mount -o remount,rw /` needed before using `sudo vim ~/. bashrc` ? and why ?

Comment: @Manish see my edits in the answer

Comment: i logged my terminal last time i had run `sudo vim ~/. bashrc` so which  `.bashrc` was that in recovery mode? `sudo vim /home/manish/.bashrc` or `sudo vim  ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @Manish  So if you logged in normally, with graphical stuff, and then opened terminal app in there, that's your  home, so `sudo vim ~/.bashrc` was for you, for `/home/yourusername`.  In recovery mode, you're automatically logged in as root, so ~ means `/root` folder. In recovery mode  `vim ~/.bashrc` means `/root/.bashrc` and you don't wanna edit that. `sudo` means run as root, but in recovery you log in as root. It  is kinda same as admin account on Windows.

Comment: so in recovery mode i should modify `vim /home/manish/.bashrc` right ?

Comment: @Manish Yes, exactly right. Could you tell us what exactly you modified in `.bashrc` and `.profile` ? Not being logged in might or might not be related to it

Comment: actually last night i was trying to add `android_home` and i started felt sleepy so i guess i did something that i dont know when today i was trying to login my login page was bouncing back after giving correct password also. So i guess there might be some changes in those file

Comment: So you can get to your login screen right ? but not past the login screen ? How about pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 ? does that bring you to a command line ? can you log in there ? ( by the way , you can go back to graphics from Ctrl + Alt + F2  by pressing Ctrl + Alt +F7 ) .

Comment: @Manish if you can login there in Ctrl + Alt + F2 (this is called tty , by the way), then can you please run `ls -l .Xauthority` ? Bouncing login screen is a common problem when this file gets changed by Ubuntu automatically. Tell us what `ls -l . Xauthority` tells you . If you see `-rw------- 1 root root 201 May 21 22:56 .Xauthority`, then this is your main problem, not .bashrc

Comment: in that case what will be solution? by the way ctrl+alt+f2 doesnt show anything

Comment: If that is the case, you need to look at this: http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/295286

Comment: Basically if everything is normal, you should see output of `ls -l .Xauthority` like this: `-rw------- 1 manish manish 201 May 21 22:56 .Xauthority` . This is correct. `-rw------- 1 root root 201 May 21 22:56 .Xauthority` is not correct. You need to change ownership of that file to your username. Like this `sudo chown manish:manish /home/manish/.Xauthority`

Comment: but  ctrl+alt+f2 doesnt show anything on login screen page

Comment: @Manish That's unusual. What about others ?  Ctrl + Alt + F3  or Ctrl + Alt + F4 ? If you dont' see anything there also, then proceed with recovery mode, forget about Ctrl + Alt + F2 for now. You can look at `ls -l /home/username/.Xauthority` also. By the way, you noticed that dot before X, right ? it's important to include it

Comment: @Manish I will need to leave to sleep now, but I will come back later. I'm currious how your problem gets resolved

Comment: What you should be seeing when you press Ctrl + Alt + F2 or F3 shoudl look like this: http://www.labtestproject.com/files/linuse/virtual_terminal/virtual_terminal_tty2_b.png

Comment: oki will try and let u know

Comment: I just undo all changes made to my `.profile` & `bashrc` file by following your discussion

Comment: Everything works now ? Congrats ! How about ctrl + alt + f2 ?

Comment: Yah got my system back. I didnt try `ctrl+alt+f2`.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to notice that there is nothing called `safe mode` in Ubuntu. Here we have `Recovery Mode`.

And if you mean Recovery mode then I could say you yes you can do what you want and you can edit those `.profile` and `.bashrc` files.

You have to notice when running in recovery mode the file system  usually mounted in read only mode so you have to remount it with rw.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Once you do  that you can able to edit the files. and note you dont have to use sudo since you'll be using root. **So please be careful not to broke your system, for that I prefer you to use live CD**

Or you can also use the Live CD to do the same task. Just mount your harddisk when you boot from live cd then navigate to the files and do what you want to do.

Comment: so I can use something like `sudo vim ~/. bashrc` ??

Comment: You don't need sudo in recovery mode. It's run by root already

Comment: As serg answered above you dont need sudo, In case of live CD you can use sudo

Comment: But of course when you are logged in as root, `~/` won't be **your** home directory - you will need to use an explicit path like `/home/manish/`