# How to repair a edited file in /usr/gnome-shell/share/ theme/ in root mode

Tags: 18.04, lts

I edited a file in `/usr/gnome-shell/share/theme/ubuntu.css`. I  did the editing in the block #lockDialogGroup  I used the wrong syntax and  my computer will not boot.  What commands would I use  safe mode root@Douce (my computer name) to re-edit the file so my computer will boot. I don't want to do a fresh install.

Comment: You can boot in safe mode, go to root console, remount `/` and then edit the file. Another way is to boot from LiveUSB and edit from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify bashrc & .profile from safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626836/modify-bashrc-profile-from-safe-mode)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution will be to reinstall [its `gnome-shell-common` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ubuntu.css&searchon=contents) from simple terminal session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-common
```

to revert file to the default contents.